# How to redirect http to https and https://www to https://

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

I need help with rewrite rules.

So I want that these addresses:

```
http://domain.com
http://www.domain.com
https://www.domain.com
```

Redirect to:

```
https://domain.com
```

Can someone help me?

Right now I have rule:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [R,L]

But it doesnt redirect https://www to https://
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```