# Redirect http://www. and http:// to https for both root and subdomain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following rules in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This causes domains such as `http://www.domain.com` to be redirected to `https://domain.com` as well as `http://www.sub.domain.com` to be redirected to `https://sub.domain.com`.

I would like to expand this rule to include redirection from `http://domain.com` to `https://domain.com` and `http://sub.domain.com` to `https://sub.domain.com`.

I've found a couple of examples online, but they don't seem to do quite what I would like:

- [How to redirect http to https and https://www to https://](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297747/how-to-redirect-http-to-https-and-https-www-to-https) This example appears to hardcode domain and not support subdomain?
- [Redirect all http AND https non-www URLS to https://www.xyz.com via htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638611/redirect-all-http-and-https-non-www-urls-to-https-www-xyz-com-via-htaccess) This is close, but is going to www not away from it which changes the regex.

I know this isn't a difficult change, but PHP/.htaccess files aren't my strongest suite. Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: There's `%{HTTPS} == 'on'` to signify if https is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rule that lets you do both redirects in one single rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}::%{HTTPS} ^(?:www\.(.+?)::o(?:ff|n)|(?!www\.)(.+?)::off)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

It will do following redirections:

1. `http://domain.com         => https://domain.com`
2. `http://www.domain.com     => https://domain.com`
3. `https://www.domain.com    => https://domain.com`
4. `http://www.sub.domain.com => https://sub.domain.com`